# Check if a string contains 'http://' and '.jpg'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im new to Ruby and Rails so forgive me if this an easy question. Im trying to check when a user passes in an IMG url in my form, that it is a valid url. Here is my code:

```
if params[:url].include? 'http://' && (params[:url].include? '.jpg' || params[:url].include? '.png')
```

This returns and error. Is this is even the best way to go about it? What should I do differently? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular expressions... [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if my_str =~ %r{\Ahttps?://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png)\z}i
```

Regex explained:

- `%r{...}` — regex literal similar to `/.../`, but allows `/` to be used inside without escaping
- `\A` — the start of the string (`^` is just the start of the line)
- `http`  — the literal text
- `s?`  — optionally followed by an "s" (to allow https://)
- `://` — the literal text (to prevent something like `http-whee.jpg`)
- `.+`  — one or more characters (that aren't a newline)
- `\.`  — a literal period (make sure this is an extension we're looking at)
- `(?:aaa|bbb)` — allow either `aaa` or `bbb` here, but don't capture the result
- `jpe?g` — either "jpg" or "jpeg"
- `png` — the literal text
- `\z` — the end of the string (`$` is just the end of the line)
- `i` — make the match case-insensitive (allow for `.JPG` as well as `.jpg`)

However, you might be able to get away with just this (more readable) version:

```
allowed_extensions = %w[.jpg .jpeg .png]
if my_str.start_with?('http://') &&
   allowed_extensions.any?{ |ext| my_str.end_with?(ext) }
```

Comment: @Deekor See my edit for an answer that is more readable (if not quite so powerful)

Comment: @Phrogz just tried it with the extension .ktl and it got through :/

Comment: @Phrogz nvm I accidentally tested on my PROD enviorment not DEV. Works great thanks again!

Comment: @undur_gongor Good call; added. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

@Phrogz answer is better,I just tried this with some ruby libs.

```
require 'uri'

extensions = %w( .jpg .jpeg .png )
schemes = %w( http https )
string = params[:url]

if (schemes.include?URI.parse(string).scheme) && (extensions.include?File.extname(string))

end
```

Answer (score 1):

While regex will shorten the code, I prefer to not do such a check all in one pattern. It's a self-documentation/maintenance thing. A single regex is faster, but if the needed protocols or image types grow, the pattern will become more and more unwieldy.

Here's what I'd do:

```
str[%r{^http://}i] && str[/\.(?:jpe?g|png)$/]
```